# Keyboard shortcut for keyboard layout switch in fedora 16

Tags: fedora, shortcuts, language, layout

I've just installed Fedora 16 x64 with Gnome 3.1 on my laptop and have some little but very annoying problem - I can't set keyboard shortcut for switching keyboard layouts(simply switching languages) so every time I have to use mou

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L']"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to the regional and language settings by clicking on your
   language
2. Then choose the layout tab
3. Click option button
4. Chose key(s) to change layout
5. Select your favorite

Comment: why the reverse of it doesn't work? I use Shift+Ctrl and it changes from en to fa but if I press Shift+Ctrl againt it doesn't change it from fa to en.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the default keyboard shortcut which is <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> ("super" is another name for the Windows key)

Comment: Thanks alot, this is the correct answer as of now, the settings described in the accepted answer seem to have moved