# How to reverse the keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, keyboard-layout

I added a keyboard shortcut to change the keyboard layout as [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/373543/keyboard-shortcut-for-keyboard-layout-switch-in-fedora-16).

Reversing it doesn't work though. I can change the language from EN to FA by pressing Right <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but when I press Right <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> again it doesn't change back from FA to EN.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I only know Windows, but hypotheses are 1. alt-ctrl is not "toggle languages" but "change to EN", and you need to look into those settings, or 2. the FA keyboard layout, whatever it is, doesn't have the alt and/or ctrl keys perform the same actions.

Comment: That is very strange, I use the same proceedure as described in the link you gave and happily cycle between gr,es and en. What version of gnome (you _are_ using gnome right?) are you using?

Comment: @terdon (yes, I'm using gnome!) I'm using gnome 3.4.1

Comment: @terdon the left 'Alt' + 'Control' works but right doesn't! I edited the question.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee, ah, that may be because in some layouts the right Alt is called "AltGr" and treated as another key. I would guess this is the case for the FA layout, so when you are using it the combination no longer works because the right Alt is not "Alt" but "AltGr".